# How to stop spring KafkaMessageListenerContainer reconnection attempts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka

I have a [KafkaMessageListenerContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.html) instance, I'm calling `container.start()` with wrong kafka server address, but no exception is thrown in the start method, instead my app runs in a loop with the following output:

```
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:19093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I want to stop this loop when connection is not working or make the start method throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `spring.kafka.admin.fail-fast` configuration property to `true`.

The default is `false`.

More on the configuration properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.integration)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no kafka-clients API to detect whether the server is available or not.